AC Condenser Motor Only Runs Correctly in One Direction
The bearings on my condenser fan motor started going out (loud squealing) on my unit, so I replaced it, along with a new matching capacitor, both items provided by a reputable supply house.  New motor is a Mars 10458, and the new capacitor is a Titan Pro TRCFD5075.  The old motor spun in a direction that drew air in through the fins/over coils, then up and out (i.e. standard).  The new one when mounted the way it came wired out of the box spun in the opposite direction, drawing air in from the top and out through the sides.
The new motor has wires running out of, then back in to the motor housing while the original motor did not. My understanding is simply switching these connections is the normal solution to my "reverse-running" situation. Also, while maybe not relevant to this question, the old motor had only three wires running out and down to capacitor (black, yellow, brown) while the new motor has four (4th being a multicolored white/brown); I did nothing with the new/4th wire other than secure it out of the way.
So I swapped connections to the only other one possible, given constraint of male/female ends of leads. The motor/fan did then run in the correct direction, but struggled to get going and did not reach full, rated RPMs, and also get pretty hot (I only let in run for a minute or two like this). So there's some issue.
Since I didn’t think the fan was moving enough air through at that point to be efficient, and also maybe that something was actually harmful with this configuration and I didn’t want to leave it running in a manner that may have hurt the motor or compressor or whatever, I switched the connections back to how they were out of the box...at least in that configuration sufficient fan speed and air was being moved through unit, and inside the temp drops at registers were my usual 15-16 degrees.
So I'm left wondering if it is a faulty brand-new motor, the brand-new capacitor that works just fine/as expected when motor runs in "wrong" direction, or something about how I wired everything (hard to mess up, frankly).
I have some pics, but didn't want to add a bunch of possibly unhelpful content that might only be distracting. Fundamental question here is why would a brand-new motor and capacitor work just fine in one direction but not the other.
Also : While I do not plan on leaving air flow as is, my understanding is that this is not specifically harming anything in the system (it may, of course, be causing issues with whatever is being hit by all that hot air being ejected radially at ground level.) If there is concern it is possibly doing harm to AC system or any components as is, please let me know.
=========================================
Adding some pics for clarity:

Semi-crappy pic of wiring diagram on motor:



Clear wiring diagram from internet for the Mars motor seems to be here (at least URL says 10458, actual picture indicates different fan model but it is virtually identical except for capacitance rating):



Wiring diagram/info from inside of condenser unit cover:



Also including pic for capacitor as currently wired:



Contacts current wiring (note: here and above, all (3) wires with protective blue plastic covering are the leads from new motor):



Original capacitor wiring for non-reversible motor:



The motor you linked is reversable The plate on the motor will show the wiring to switch directions. The Compressor / Condenser unit is engineered for its airflow a specific direction.

You don't just randomly swap wires to alter direction on a motor. You follow the instructions which are typically on a label on the motor, or which you find from the manufacturer. That usually involves a screwdriver and/or wire-nuts, often in a covered wiring compartment, not wires sticking out of the motor with spade connectors (those are for connecting to other things.)

@Ecnerwal: the swap was not random...did you take a look at link to pic of actual motor?  I am referring to the orange/brown/yellow/purple wires.  From internet on this exact, specific subject: “A manually reversible electric motor can be reversed or changed by switching two wires. There will typically be a yellow and purple wire in the motor that can be reversed by switching them up. Yellow to yellow rotates clockwise while yellow to purple runs counterclockwise.” Seems straightforward enough except the colors referenced don’t exactly match the color/connections of wires I am seeing.

@Ecnerwal: (continued) And this approach to reverse directions was confirmed by supply house where I purchased as well as a former HVAC licenses contractor (retired).  In other words, that's how the motor was designed, to be this simple to reverse.  If there is a way to get to a "covered wiring compartment", it is not >>at all<< apparent to me after thoroughly looking.

And to beat a dead horse: https://youtu.be/dKkafL5-bdI?si=AKukv1yGg50VFhBF&t=310

@RMDman: you have offered good opinion/insight on HVAC questions in the past...do you have any thoughts on main question in OP?

I can't find a decent connection diagram from Mars -- would you include a photo of the diagram on the label of your motor? Also, double-check that you have the three wires correctly connected. One goes to the Fan terminal on the dual-run cap. Another goes to the same contactor pole as the Common terminal of the cap does, and the third goes to the opposite contactor pole. Make sure these latter two aren't swapped. Do they need to be reversed when motor direction is reversed? The connection diagram should indicate.

@GregHill: Thanks...i didn't get an email notification as usual, so just seeing this today.  Yes, odd that diagrams are so hard to come by online.  I'll get some pics added to OP sometime this a.m. (where I am).

@GregHill: pics have been added...hopefully they add clarity rather than create confusion.  "Do they need to be reversed when motor direction is reversed?"...that is the question that really needs an answer!

The fact that the diagram shows a single capacitor connected to the two brown wires without any connection to mains power, and the fact that one can optionally use a dual capacitor (which does connect to one pole of mains power) and leave the brown-white wire insulated, imply that there must be some internal connection between the start winding and the main winding.
If you wanted to, without buying any additional parts, you could test what this motor would do when wired with a single capacitor. Disconnect everything except the brown wire from the dual capacitor, disconnect the yellow or the black wire going to the compressor, and connect the brown-white wire to the C terminal of the dual capacitor. When mains power is applied the fan motor should start strong in one direction; if you remove power, swap the four reversing wires, and re-apply power, it should start strong in the opposite direction.
If you did do this test you could set up the motor for the required direction of rotation and then while operating measure AC volts from the brown-white wire to the yellow and to the black wires. If the measurement from brown-white to black comes up around 0 volts I would consider that validation that yes phasing of the brown and the yellow/black matters, and black is the one that should have been connected to the C pole of the dual capacitor.

I can try this, but one thing still throws me for a loop...I installed/wired the new motor and capacitor >>exactly<< the same way the original motor was wired (I added pic of that original configuration above).  The old motor was not an (easily) reversible one...it only ran in a CW direction (as one looks down into unit from above.  So...can it be that anything in way I have wired new motor into new capacitor can account for this?  Reminder it runs just fine CCW; it's only an issue when jumpers/rotation wires are switched to CW.

@AA040371 Yesterday I installed a reversible Mars motor - different than the one here in that it was a two-speed model. It "just worked" - when I first powered it on the rotation was incorrect, so I reversed the connections for the direction, and it started and ran strong the other direction. No need to also swap the AC supply lines as I had suggested in this answer. This was with a dual run capacitor, so I had the brown-white lead disconnected/insulated. It made me wonder whether and how you might have solved your problem.

Hi Greg...thanks for checking back in.  I still am in a bit of limbo, but based on your last response, which seems to exactly correspond to how my motor is configured and what I feel should have been able to do to reverse spin, I now suspect that I just got a faulty motor, as hard as that is for me to believe.  To recap (see pics waaaay above), I also have my Br/Wh unconnected, the Br and Ye leads going to capacitor fan and common contacts, respectively, and the Bl wire connected to same side of mains contact as other Bl wire that was there.  Is this what you did as well?

@AA040371 Sounds like we've both followed instructions the same way. You might measure the capacitor to be sure it really is 7.5 uF (it's probably fine, considering the motor starts fine in one direction). Still would be interesting to see whether your motor runs poorly with Br/Wh connected to the cap common (and yellow wires removed from cap common). If it runs poorly that way too the motor definitely would be defective.

Oops...I was remiss in not updating:  I finally determined that since it was nothing else (capacitor, wiring, etc.) it was the motor that was defective.  So I got a new one, put in just like before, and it worked as expected.  It's worth noting that while the fan was operating in reverse, my system was far less efficient (poor delta-T)...I suspect the compressor was moving into an overload situation during the hottest of the days recently.  But happy all is back to status quo :--)
